# Поиск пользователя по введенной строке

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте.
Есть объект пользователь, у него есть поле *description* где описаны его интересы. Пользователь на сайте через знак *#* вводит данные(т.е. интересы) и нужно найти всех пользователей, у которых есть хоть один из введенных интересов.
на js перешел вчера, но логика предыдущих яп говорит, что нужно перегрузить стандартный метод *find()*, но что-то у меня не получается

```
async findPeople(ctx, next){
    var search = ctx.request.body;
    var arr = JSON.stringify(search.search.toString().split("#"));
    console.log(arr);
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        var user = await User.find({ description: function(){
            if(User.description.toString().indexOf(arr[i]) > -1){ 
              return User.description;
            }
            else{
             return "";
            }}
        });
    }
    ctx.result = user;
    await next();
},
```

в *search* я получаю в виде объекта строку, которую ввел пользователь, потом преобразую в массив строк. В **User.find({ description: function()})** предполагается, что *function()* вернет результат, по которому и будет вестись поиск.

Скорее, это ближе к истине

```
user = await User.find({ description: function(){
            if(description.toString().indexOf(arr[i]) > -1){ 
              return search.search;
            }
            else{
             return "";
            }}
```

Comment: и что, каковы результаты? где поиск-то происходит?

Comment: @Igor должен в методе find(), но там что-то неправильно. в function() программа даже не заходит.
Результат- пустой список

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/markdown-docs/queries.html

```
var conditions = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  conditions.push({ description: new RegExp(arr[i]) });
}
var user = await User.find({ $or: conditions });
```